# 14.8V LiPo Battery Protection

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, protection, lipo, over-voltage-protection

**Disclaimer: This is my very first time I have to work with batteries so I have basically no idea whatsoever.**

I need to protect a [14.8V LiPo Battery](https://www.reichelt.de/akku-pack-li-polymer-14-8-v-3500-mah-25-50-c-rd-slp-3500-s4-p208387.html?&trstct=pol_2&nbc=1) from overcharging/overdischarging. I have looked up [PMICs](https://de.farnell.com/texas-instruments/bq29700dset/batt-prot-li-ion-li-pol-4-275v/dp/3123826?st=BQ29700D) but this one only works up to 8V or am I mistaken?

So my question is: do I need to program any of these PMICs or do I just put them in front of the battery and it will do it's job?

I'm sorry if this question sounds super silly and very unprofessional. But like I said, I have never worked with batteries.

Comment: What is the LiPo being used for? Yes they need to be programmed, or at least chosen correctly for your battery voltage and mAh rating (capacity). Big, high power batteries don't have PMICs (too much heat). You are just expected to manage and handle them properly.

Comment: @DKNguyen its being used to power a small computer. If I read the description of the battery correctly it seems that the battery is made of 4 cells, and a capacity of 3500mAh. Will the linked PMIC work with this battery?

Comment: No that one will not work